# How can I store a number while using multiple if statements?

Tags: python, if-statement, count

I am creating a python code for rock, paper, scissors but I can't seem to keep track of the score of wins, losses, and ties. I think there is something wrong with my "count" which i called "win += 0", "lose += 0" and "tie += 0." Could someone please tell me what I should do to increase the score by 1 every time there is a win, lose or tie?

Here is my code below:

```
from random import randint

t = ["rock", "paper", "scissors"]
computer = t[randint(0,2)]
player = False
lose = 0
win = 0

for i in range(0,10):
    print("1... 2... 3... go!")
    while player == False:
        player = input("rock, paper, scissors: ")
        print("Computer: ", computer)
        print("User: ", player)
        if player == computer:
            tie = 0
            tie +=1
            print("Tie!")
        elif player == "rock":
            if computer == "paper":
                lose +=0
                print("You lose!")
            else:
                win +=0
                print("You win!")
        elif player == "paper":
            if computer == "scissors":
                lose = 0
                lose +=0
                print("You lose!")
            else:
                win +=0
                print("You win!")
        elif player == "scissors":
            if computer == "rock":
                lose +=0
                print("You lose!")
            else:
                win +=0
                print("You win!")
        else:
            print("That's not a valid play. Check your spelling!")

        player = False
        computer = t[randint(0,2)]
        break
print("Final Tally")
print("************")
print("User Wins: ", win)
print("Computer Wins: ", lose)
print("Ties: ", tie)

if tie > win and tie > lose:
    print("It's a tie!")
elif win > tie and win > lose:
    print("You won!")
else:
    print("The computer won!")
```

Comment: `tie = 0` should be before the loop, not every time there's a tie.

Comment: `variable += 0` doesn't change the variable. If you want to add 1, it should be `+= 1`

Comment: If you want to increment a variable in this way, use `win += 1` which is the equivalent to `win = win + 1` with an `int`

Comment: FYI, `computer = random.choice(t)`.

Comment: Try this, you'll like it:

```from random import choice

t = ["rock", "paper", "scissors"]
computer = choice(t)
```

Comment: Thank you!! I fixed it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's the fixed version. I suggest you work on it some more :)

```py
from random import choice

t = ["rock", "paper", "scissors"]

tie = 0
lose = 0
win = 0

for i in range(0, 10):
    print("1... 2... 3... go!")

    # you need to refresh these variables on every for iteration
    computer = choice(t)
    player = None

    # if you're using while to make sure player inputs, that's the only thing that needs
    # to be within the while loop
    while not player:
        player = input("rock, paper, scissors: ")
    print("Computer: ", computer)
    print("User: ", player)

    # I would look for a way to simplify determining the winner
    if player == computer:
        # tie += 1 is the same as tie = tie + 1
        tie +=1
        print("Tie!")
    elif player == "rock":
        if computer == "paper":
            lose += 1
            print("You lose!")
        else:
            win += 1
            print("You win!")
    elif player == "paper":
        if computer == "scissors":
            lose += 1
            print("You lose!")
        else:
            win += 1
            print("You win!")
    elif player == "scissors":
        if computer == "rock":
            lose += 1
            print("You lose!")
        else:
            win += 1
            print("You win!")
    else:
        print("That's not a valid play. Check your spelling!")


print("Final Tally")
print("************")
print("User Wins: ", win)
print("Computer Wins: ", lose)
print("Ties: ", tie)

if tie > win and tie > lose:
    print("It's a tie!")
elif win > tie and win > lose:
    print("You won!")
else:
    print("The computer won!")
```

UPDATE: Apparently I have nothing to do. So ok, here's a straightforward way to simplify win conditioning.

```py
    win_condition_rock = player == 'rock' and computer == 'scissors'
    win_condition_paper = player == 'paper' and computer == 'rock'
    win_condition_scissors = player == 'scissors' and computer == 'paper'

    if player == computer:
        # tie += 1 is the same as tie = tie + 1
        tie +=1
        print("Tie!")

    elif any([win_condition_paper, win_condition_scissors, win_condition_rock]):
        win += 1
        print('You win')

    else:
        lose += 1
        print('You lose')
```

UPDATE 2: And here's a check for valid input

```py
    while player not in t:
        player = input("rock, paper, scissors: ").lower()
        if player not in t:
            print('Invalid input')
```